# Returns the largest n such that R[n] = S

Tags: python, memory, out-of-memory, scalability, space-complexity

> Write a function answer(str_S) which, given the base-10 string
>   representation of an integer S, returns the largest n such that R(n) =
>   S. Return the answer as a string in base-10 representation. If there
>   is no such n, return "None". S will be a positive integer no greater
>   than 10^25.
>
> where R(n) is the number of zombits at time n:

```
R(0) = 1
R(1) = 1
R(2) = 2
R(2n) = R(n) + R(n + 1) + n (for n > 1)
R(2n + 1) = R(n - 1) + R(n) + 1 (for n >= 1)

Test cases
==========

Inputs:
    (string) str_S = "7"
Output:
    (string) "4"

Inputs:
    (string) str_S = "100"
Output:
    (string) "None"
```

My program below is correct but it is not scalable since here the range of S can be a very large number like 10^24. Could anyone help me with some suggestion to improve the code further so that it can cover any input case.

```
def answer(str_S):

    d = {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2}
    str_S = int(str_S)
    i = 1
    while True:

        if i > 1:
            d[i*2] = d[i] + d[i+1] + i
            if d[i*2] == str_S:
                return i*2
            elif d[i*2] > str_S:
                return None

        if i>=1:
            d[i*2+1] = d[i-1] + d[i] + 1
            if d[i*2+1] == str_S:
                return i*2 + 1
            elif d[i*2+1] > str_S:
                return None

        i += 1

print answer('7')
```

Comment: [Cross-posted on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/104464/9357)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, where are you having trouble with the scaling?  I ran your code on a 30-digit number, and it seemed to complete okay.  Do you have a memory limit?  Python handles arbitrarily large integers, although very large ones get flipped into digital arithmetic mode.

Given the density of R values, I suspect that you can save space as well as time if you switch to a straight array: use the value as an array index instead of a dict key.

Comment: I ran this program with 20 digits and my computer hanged :D. Anyway, this is a coding competition question and I am running in there platform. Throws memory error

Comment: Program should cover all the cases, unfortunately this is occupying two much memory because of dictionary data structure.

Comment: I find it very strange that the competition allows you to solicit other people for help.  Explain?

Comment: I am not taking part in competition but solving questions for fun and learning. Anyone can access their questions set and run in their platform.

Comment: Much better; thanks.

If you are limited in memory, then you cannot maintain arbitrary amounts of reference data; you will have to recompute it as needed.  You are presently keeping on the order of N entries for computing answer(N).  However, the computational depth of the definition is log2(N).

I believe that you need to sacrifice computing time for memory: write a recursive routine to compute R(N).  Note that R(N) bears a general relationship to the value of N; if you can characterize this, you can reduce the range of N values you try.

Does this help?